# How to decline a specific day but accept all others in a recurring Outlook meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I attend daily standups with one of our development teams.  On Thursdays, I have a conflict but can attend all other days.  Is there a way to decline all Thursdays going forward, while accepting any other day?

Currently, I decline each Thursday individually, which isn't ideal.

Did a pretty extensive search and found plenty of answers around declining all meetings after specific dates, but nothing on this specific use case. But I'm sure I'm not the only one with this scenario!

I use outlook on both PC and Mac, if that affects the answer.

Comment: @harrymc The answer provided in that post is pretty much what I'm currently doing - manually removing myself (ie. declining) every individual Thursday.  What I'm looking for (and maybe it doesn't exist) is a way to do a Recurring decline of some kind, so that it automatically declines all Thursdays in perpetuity, while keeping me in Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, and Friday meetings.

Comment: When you open a meeting series (even if it's one that someone else set up), can you adjust the recurrences for just your calendar?

Comment: @harrymc I can, but the reasoning behind declining is so that the Scrum master and the rest of the team are aware that I won't be attending.  Unless I'm mistaken, adjusting on just my calendar will remain local. I'll double check though.

Comment: The only alternative to manual decline that I can see is to create a VBA macro to do it for you. But you will spend more time on it than all the declines for the coming year. Is that a solution?

Comment: @harrymc if someone writes such macro, it will save time for the hundreds of people who need it…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in feature available in Outlook to do a "recurring decline". As an alternative, you may accept the meeting first, then open your calendar and delete multiple occurrences on Thursday in a row:

1. Press Ctrl key to select multiple occurrences you want to decline:
   (See the occurrences below with dark black borders.)

[image]
 2.  Right click on one occurrence, click Delete

[image]

3. Click Delete this occurrence.

[image]

4. When prompted if you want to send a response to the organizer, I'd like to suggest editing a response to notify the organizer that you will be absent for all meetings on Thursday, then sending the response once.
5. Repeat Step 3, but choose Do not send a response for the second prompt to avoid sending too many notifications to the organizer.

Comment: Thanks Yuki, it's looking like this is the closest I'll get to solving this problem  Marking as answered for now, as I doubt we'll get any answers better than this one.